# Change user password from mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I tried to implement a method in my application to change the password of the logged in user.
I'm using node.js and mongodb. Just found example code directly on the official mongodb blog:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/password-authentication-with-mongoose-part-1

```
 User.findOne(req.firstname, function (err, user) {
   if (err) throw err;

   user.comparePassword(req.password, function (err, isMatch) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(isMatch); // -> Returns True if match
  });
 });      
});
```

In my user model I have the following code:

```
   userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
     console.log("candidatepw-> " + candidatePassword);
     console.log("password->" + this.password);
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
  };
```

When I saw the console.log output, I realized that the variable candidatePassword is undefined. How is that? Am I missing something? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you're expecting the password in `req.password` or in `req.body.password`?

Comment: Yes, the password is correctly set in the req.body.

Comment: What is being passed into the method for the undefined parameter?

Comment: If `candidatePassword` is undefined then either `req.password` is undefined, or `comparePassword` is being called form somewhere else.